# CSS background image doesn't show up on IE11 when on position:fixed pseudo-element

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-position, pseudo-element

JSfiddle demonstrates the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/qjtbchpu/11/

```
<div id="container">
  <article>
    blah
  </article>
  <article>
    blah
  </article>
</div>

#container::before {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
  background: url(https://imgur.com/qYUPJgv.jpg);
  position: fixed;
}

article {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  margin: 4em;
  padding: 2em;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

This works perfectly in all major browsers that I've tried, apart from IE11 where the photo only appears if I use position:absolute which doesn't give me the effect I desire.

Any known solutions or workarounds?  Thank you

Comment: Your code is working fine, maybe it  is taking time to load

Comment: There is no reason to apply **`position:fixed`** to the pseudo-element...it should be **`position:absolute`**

Comment: I tested the issue with IE 11 and I am able to produce the issue. Image is not loading at first. The strange thing is, if you resize the window than it will show the image immediately.

Comment: ...unless I want a fixed-position pseudo-element, that doesn't move as the viewport is scrolled @Paulie_D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE11 simply won't load huge images there, guess at the time of pseudo element creation, they are not in cache. Your code works just fine with some simple/small image, but for larger image (that takes time to load) you can use this trick:

```css
#container::before {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    content: url(https://imgur.com/qYUPJgv.jpg);
    background: url(https://imgur.com/qYUPJgv.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
}
article {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
    margin: 4em;
    padding: 2em;
    border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <article>
        blah
    </article>
    <article>
        blah
    </article>
</div>
```

Tested and it works fine, also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h9o7rpn6/2/).

Key line, which force browser to load the image is:

```
content: url(https://imgur.com/qYUPJgv.jpg);
```

Comment: Thanks, that totally fixed it and explains why very occasionally it WAS working in IE11.  Do you anticipate any downsides/complications to using this fix cross-browser?

Comment: Nah, that trick with text indent and overflow hidden has been used for at least 15 years (successfully).

Comment: I've used those myself before, just never put an image URL in as a pseudo-element `content` value.  I can see that it works but wasn't sure if it comes with any caveats!